# SQL Query to find all rows having two columns same i:e user_id and webinar_id?

Tags: mysql, sql

The below attached is the sample table:

The table consists of 5 columns, I want to find all rows whose (user_id and webinar_id) are not unique.

```
id | user_id | webinar_id | x | y
---+---------+------------+---+---
1  |     201 |         44 | 2 | 5
2  |     202 |         45 | 3 | 6
3  |     201 |         44 | 2 | 5
4  |     203 |         47 | 5 | 7
5  |     202 |         45 | 3 | 6
```

The desired output is:

```
id | user_id | webinar_id | x | y
---+---------+------------+---+---
1  |     201 |         44 | 2 | 5
2  |     202 |         45 | 3 | 6
```

Comment: Please don't show images. Show your data as text instead. Then you should also show the desired result. Are you asking how to find all user_id / webinar_id pairs that occur more than once in the table? Desired result would be rows 1, 2, 3, and 5? What have you tried yourself? Where are you stuck? What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: When there are 2 (or more) rows with 201/44, which one to return?

Comment: @jarlh:  First row

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: BTW: Sample data would have been better, if it included a case where the single IDs were repeated and the pair not, e.g. an additional entry for user_id 203 with webinar_id 44. Such edge cases make the requested rule much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate per user_id / webinar_id pair and count. Where there is more than one row, select the minimum ID.

```
select *
from mytable
where (user_id, webinar_id, id) in
(
  select user_id, webinar_id, min(id)
  from mytable
  group by user_id, webinar_id
  having count(*) > 1
)
order by id;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work (at least in MSSQL 2012, have no MySQL)

```
declare @tab table (id int, user_id int, webinar_id int, x int, y int)
insert into @tab (id, user_id, webinar_id, x, y)
values
(1, 201, 44, 2, 5),
(2, 202, 45, 3, 6),
(3, 201, 44, 2, 5),
(4, 203, 47, 5, 7),
(5, 202, 45, 3, 6)


;WITH groups AS (
    SELECT id, user_id, webinar_id, x, y, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY user_id) AS myRowNumber
    FROM @tab WHERE user_id IN 
    (SELECT user_id FROM @tab GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    AND
    webinar_id IN 
    (SELECT webinar_id FROM @tab GROUP BY webinar_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1))
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groups.myRowNumber=1
```

Comment: *user_id and webinar_id are not unique* is not the same as *user_id and webinar_id are equal*

Comment: @GameDroids author has changed his question

Comment: I didn't know that. @ashishmishra, could you please elaborate? Maybe you could add an example which rows exactly you would like the query to return (from the picture you are showing)

Comment: Let me know if the above question is explainable itself ?

Comment: Which MySQL version(s) will run this? (2 upvotes, how come?)

Answer (score 1):

(Query for all MySQL versions)

Have a subquery that returns the duplicated user_id and webinar_id's together with the lowest id. Join that result to get the whole rows.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select min(id) id, user_id, webinar_id
      from tablename
      group by user_id, webinar_id
      having count(*) >= 2) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
   and t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.webinar_id = t2.webinar_id
```

(The `and t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.webinar_id = t2.webinar_id` part of the `WHERE` clause is only needed if the id column may contain duplicates.)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `exists`.  You specify that you want *all* rows, although that is not what your results show:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                    t2.webinar_id = t.webinar_id and
                    t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(user_id, webinar_id, id)`.  I would expect this to have the better performance than almost any other method (at least on larger tables).

If you want only the row with the smallest id:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                    t2.webinar_id = t.webinar_id and
              having count(*) >= 2
             );
```